# Correct FQDN Uri invalidate by apache commons UrlValidator

Tags: java, regex, apache

First of all, I'm using current version of `UrlValidator` library by Apache Commons. I'm trying to validate FQDN URL like `tcp://cor.rect.url:61616`, but unfortunately, the Validator invalidates this URL. I'm creating Validator with the following arguments:

```
new UrlValidator(UrlValidator.ALLOW_ALL_SCHEMES + UrlValidator.ALLOW_LOCAL_URLS)
```

Did anyone meet similar problem before? Is there any workaround?

Comment: `UrlValidator`, which calls [`DomainValidator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/src-html/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.html) to check whether the URL has valid TLD (`isValidInfrastructureTld`, `isValidGenericTld`, and `isValidCountryCodeTld`), with allow local URL, it checks `isValidLocalTld`, but `url` is not among the list of TLD, so your URL is rejected.

Comment: That was correct, thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to the source code of [`UrlValidator`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.java#L403)<sup>1</sup>, it calls [`DomainValidator`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.java), which [validates the TLD in the URL](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.java#L165).

<sup><sup>1</sup> Fully qualified class name is `org.apache.commons.validator.routines.UrlValidator`, not to be confused with the deprecated implementation `org.apache.commons.validator.UrlValidator`</sup>

`DomainValidator` calls [`isValidTld`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.java#L197) to check the TLD. With `ALLOW_LOCAL_URLS` option enable, it first checks the domain name against the list of local TLDs in `isValidLocalTld`, then it checks the domain against `isValidInfrastructureTld`, `isValidGenericTld`, and `isValidCountryCodeTld`. However, `url` does not present in any of the lists.

With local URLs allowed, `DomainValidator` has a final check for [domain name without dot](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/DomainValidator.java#L168) for local URL (e.g. `localhost`), but your URL doesn't fall into this case either.

Therefore, your URL is rejected by `UrlValidator`.

As for the solution, it seems that you can define your own [`RegexValidator`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/RegexValidator.html) and passes it into [`UrlValidator(RegexValidator authorityValidator, long options)`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.html#UrlValidator(org.apache.commons.validator.routines.RegexValidator,%20long)) constructor. It might be a good idea to use the source code of [`DomainValidator.isValidAuthority`](https://github.com/apache/commons-validator/blob/VALIDATOR_1_5_1/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/UrlValidator.java#L379) as reference to parse the domain from the authority part and provide your own logic to validate the domain.